# Can noble gases emit infrared?

Tags: electromagnetic-radiation, gas, infrared-radiation

So from my understanding infrared radiation can be emitted due to rotation and stretches in a intramolecular bond and by the emission of an electron from the Paschen Series.

Considering noble gases are monoatomic, meaning they don't have those rotations and stretches, would they be able to emit infrared? I am not sure if their electrons could emit it.

Additionally, could interatomic bonds, like the Van der Waals forces, somehow create a sufficient dipole for the atom to emit infrared?

Thank you

Comment: Googling the spectrum of argon gives almost nothing but infrared.

Comment: @DKNguyen     Actually, argon produces quite a lot of visible emission, along with the near IR.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't see why noble gases cannot emit infrared radiation, as the energy difference between highly excited levels can be arbitrarily small. See also a direct [report](https://nvlpubs.nist.gov/nistpubs/jres/049/2/V49.N02.A04.pdf) on infrared emission from noble gases.